# Why do i have to use "self" in multiple inheritance when i'm not forced to use it in single inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

in this example :

```
class Dinosaur:
  def __init__(self, size, weight):
    self.size = size
    self.weight = weight
    
class Carnivore:
  def __init__(self, diet):
    self.diet = diet
    
class Tyrannosaurus(Dinosaur, Carnivore):
  def __init__(self, size, weight, diet):
    Dinosaur.__init__(self, size, weight)
    Carnivore.__init__(self, diet)
    
tiny = Tyrannosaurus(12, 14, "whatever it wants")
```

i have to mention "self" in both

```
    Dinosaur.__init__(self, size, weight)
    Carnivore.__init__(self, diet)
```

or i get an error.

but in single inheritance

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, age, occupation):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.occupation = occupation

class Superhero(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, occupation, secret_identity):
        super().__init__(name, age, occupation)
        self.secret_identity = secret_identity
```

i didn't have to mention self in the init method

```
super().__init__(name, age, occupation)
```

i'm wondering what is exactly going on under the hood that returns from **super().**init**(...)** without mentioning "self"

and what is going on in multiple inheritance that i HAVE to use "self" or i get an error

Comment: This isn't the right way to write an `__init__` method with multiple inheritance. The proper way is for every class (including the base classes) to call `super().__init__` with all leftover arguments. See https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of single-vs-multiple inheritance. It's the difference between hardcoding the class names vs using `super`.

`Dinosaurs.__init__` is a specific reference to a *function*;  no `method` object is created, and so nothing is implicitly wrapping the `self` argument and you have to supply it explicitly.

`super().__init__`, on the other hand, *does* produce a `method` argument that wraps `self` (which was, due to some compiler magic, treated as a default argument to `super` itself).

You could have used `super` in the multiple-inheritance example, in which case you would not have had to pass `self` as an explicit argument. In fact, `super` was invented to ease the definition of code that uses multiple inheritance.

```
class Dinosaur:
    def __init__(self, size, weight, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = size
        self.weight = weight
    
class Carnivore:
    def __init__(self, diet, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.diet = diet
    
class Tyrannosaurus(Dinosaur, Carnivore):
      pass

tiny = Tyrannosaurus(size=12, weight=14, diet="whatever it wants")
```

See https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for an explanation of why I used keyword argument in this fashion, as well as why both `Dinosaur` and `Carnivore` call `super`.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks; I was in the middle of fixing that, but you beat me to it ;)